# how to import nodejs projects into nodejs eclipse in mac

Tags: eclipse, node.js

I have cloned a project and try to load into nodejseclipse(mac) as file system or existing project. but it does load only root folder js files. it does not load all folder structures into eclipse. can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 19):

You need install `nodeclipse`, first.

1. `npm install -g nodeclipse` to install it
2. Go to your folder, `nodeclipse -g` to generate nodeclipse project setting.
3. Open it from Eclipse "import from other projects".

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. (Just you may need to install nodeclipse plugin to your eclipse ide as well)

Answer (score 8):

It is not quite intuitive, but the following worked for me.

Move the project into the workspace directory. Then:

**File** > **New** > **Project ...**

Under **Nodeclipse** select **Node.js Project** and **next >**.

Under **Project name:** type the same name as the project you are importing and press **Finish**.

Now you should have the project visible in the *Package Explorer*.

---

To make `.*` files visible press the small arrow in the *Package Explorer* (top right) > **Filters ...**.

Deselect **.* resources** > **OK**.

Comment: Thanks it is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

File -> New Project -> Node.js Project -> Project Name (Give some relevant name)

Next click on "Use default location" checkbox to check it off.

Next browse to the location where project has been cloned/exists

Finish.

Answer (score 0):

Created a project folder in eclipse. Dragged the source and drop into project folder in eclipse. and then linked the source folder